# React Native Picker Select: What defines clickable area?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-picker-select, react-native-picker

I'm using [react-native-picker-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picker-select) and sometimes when I click it, it doesn't open the picker. There are a few different `style` properties, but I'm wondering which one, if I apply `borderWidth: 1` to it, will enclose the area that is clickable, and outside of it not clickable?